# Utility to edit config files globally

Tags: bash, linux

I wrote a small utility in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) that allows me to edit config files anywhere. So, whenever I want to edit a config file, I don't have to type its full path or have to remember where it is.

First, I have to do:

```
$ edfig add <name> <config file path>
```

Then, I will be able to edit the corresponding config file by:

```
$ edfig <name>
```

Code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
# edfig.sh -- Config file manager
# @annahri

set -o nounset

config_list="$HOME/.config/configs.list"
CMD="${0##*/}"
EDITOR="${EDITOR:-vi}"

short_usage() {
    echo -e "${bold}Usage:${reset} $CMD [subcommand|name] [...]"
}

usage() {
    short_usage
    echo -e >&2
    echo -e "${bold}Subcommands:${reset}" >&2
    echo -e "  ${bold}add${reset}    Add new config file to list" >&2
    echo -e "  ${bold}rm${reset}     Remove config file from list" >&2
    echo -e "  ${bold}edit${reset}   Edit an entry" >&2
    echo -e "  ${bold}ls${reset}     List all stored configs" >&2
    echo -e "  ${bold}help${reset}   Print this" >&2
    echo -e >&2
    echo -e "${bold}Example:${reset}" >&2
    echo -e "  $CMD add vim \"\$HOME/.vimrc\"" >&2
    echo -e "  $CMD vim" >&2
    echo -e "  $CMD edit vim" >&2
    echo -e "  $CMD rm vim" >&2
    echo -e "  $CMD ls" >&2
    echo -e >&2
    echo -e "$CMD is a command line tool to ease config files editing" >&2
    exit
}

#=============================================================
# Colors
#=============================================================
bold='\e[1m'
red='\033[1;31m'
green='\033[1;32m'
reset='\033[0m'
#=============================================================

#=============================================================
# Helper Functions
#=============================================================
msg_error() { echo -e "  ${red}x$reset $1" >&2 && exit "$2"; }
msg_ok() { echo -e "  ${green}v$reset $1" >&2; }

#=============================================================

#=============================================================
# Edfig main functions
#=============================================================
#
# Get config file path from the specified config name
#
config_getPath() {
    sed -n "s/^$1 *= \([^ ]*.*\)/\1/p" "$config_list"
}

#
# Add new config path to list
#
config_add() {
    test "$#" -ne 2 &&
        msg_error "Usage: $CMD add <name> <config path>" 8

    local name="$1"
    local path="${2:-}"

    case "$name" in
        add|edit|rm|ls|help)
            msg_error "Reserved name. Please use another." 1
            ;;
        *)
            if [[ "${name:0:1}" =~ ^.*([!?.,])+.*$ ]]; then
                msg_error "Cannot use ${bold}${name:0:1}${reset} as the begining of name." 1
            fi
            ;;
    esac

    test -f "$path" ||
        msg_error "Not found: $path" 9

    echo -e "$name = $path" | tee -a "$config_list" > /dev/null ||
        msg_error "Cannot add new config." 7

    msg_ok "New config has been added."
    exit
}

#
# Modify specified config name and its path
# `edfig edit` with no argument will edit entire configs.list
#
config_edit() {
    local name="${1:-}"

    test -z "$name" &&
        if ! $EDITOR "$config_list" 2> /dev/null; then
            msg_error "Cannot execute $EDITOR. Exiting" 3
        fi

    awk '{print $1}' "$config_list" | grep -qw "$name" ||
        msg_error "Config for ${bold}$name${reset} not found in $config_list" 1

    cleanup() { rm -f "$tempfile"; }
    trap cleanup EXIT INT QUIT

    tempfile=$(mktemp /tmp/config-XXX.tmp)
    linenum=$(grep -wn "$name" "$config_list" | cut -d: -f1)

    grep -w "$name" "$config_list" | tee "$tempfile" > /dev/null ||
        msg_error "Error ocurred." 2

    raw="$(head -1 "$tempfile")"

    $EDITOR "$tempfile" 2> /dev/null ||
        msg_error "Error on $EDITOR. Aborting" 3

    test $(grep '\S' "$tempfile" | wc -l) -ne 1 &&
        msg_error "Invalid syntax. Must not contain multiple lines." 8

    test "$raw" == "$(head -1 "$tempfile")" &&
        msg_ok "No changes." && exit

    line="$(sed 's/"/\\"/g;s/\//\\\//g' "$tempfile")"

    sed "${linenum}s/.*/$line/" "$config_list" | sponge "$config_list" ||
        msg_error "Error editing entry." 4

    msg_ok "Successfully edited."
    cleanup &&
        trap -- EXIT INT QUIT

    exit
}

#
# Delete a config from list
#
config_rm() {
    local name="${1:-}"
    test "$name" ||
        msg_error "What to remove?" 1

    line=$(awk -v name="$name" '$1 == name' "$config_list")

    test "$line" ||
        msg_error "Config for ${bold}$name${reset} not found in $config_list" 1

    cleanup() { rm -f "$tempfile"; }
    trap cleanup EXIT INT QUIT

    tempfile=$(mktemp /tmp/configs-XXX.tmp)

    tee "$tempfile" < "$config_list" > /dev/null ||
        msg_error "Unable to make temporary copy of $(basename $config_list)." 2


    grep -v "$line" "$tempfile" | tee "$config_list" > /dev/null ||
        msg_error "Unable to remove ${bold}$name${reset} from list" 4

    msg_ok "Successfully removed."

    cleanup &&
        trap -- EXIT INT QUIT

    exit
}

#
# List all stored configs
#
config_ls() {
    echo -e "${bold}Stored Configs:${reset}"
    grep -v '^#' "$config_list" | \
        sort | \
        column -s= -t | \
        awk '{print " ",$0}'

    exit
}

#=============================================================

#
# Begin Script, argument parsing
#
test "$#" -eq 0 &&
    short_usage && exit

case "$1" in
    add|rm|edit|ls)
        _cmd="$1"; shift
        config_${_cmd} "$@"
        ;;
    help|-h|--help) usage ;;
    *) name="$1" ;;
esac

test -s "$config_list" ||
    msg_error "$config_list doesn't exist or is empty. Try adding something first.\n edfig add <name> <path>" 13

#
# Get config path and check if it's existed
#
config_path=$(config_getPath "$name")
test "$config_path" ||
    msg_error "${bold}$name${reset} doesn't exist in configs list." 1

#
# Trap EXIT QUIT INT signal to clean temporary file
#
cleanup() { rm -f "$config_tmp"; }
trap cleanup EXIT QUIT INT

config_file="${config_path##*/}"
config_tmp="/tmp/edfig-${name}-$config_file"

cp "$config_path" "$config_tmp" 2> /dev/null ||
    msg_error "Error creating temporary file. Aborting" 10

$EDITOR "${config_tmp}" 2> /dev/null ||
    msg_error "Cannot execute $EDITOR. Exiting" 3

diff "$config_tmp" "$config_path" &> /dev/null &&
    msg_ok "No changes." && exit

tee "$config_path" < "$config_tmp" > /dev/null ||
    msg_error "Cannot save changes. Aborting" 11

msg_ok "Saving changes."

cleanup && exit
```

configs.list example:

```
i3 = "/home/user/.config/i3/config"
vim = "/home/user/.vimrc"
bash = "/home/user/.bashrc"
```

Is there something I can improve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get that it's been *a while* since you posted this, and you might have fixed any number of these issues already. Still, I was bored, so here I am, pointing them out, hoping some of it will help.

### config_getPath

Depending on what `$1` contains, this might not be well-behaved - consider cases like `config_getPath '.*|'` - that turns into `sed s/^.*| *= \([^ ]*.*\)/\1/p` which probably isn't what you want.

There *are* ways to somewhat-robustly escape strings for use in `sed` patterns, but you may want to look into a different approach to reading, and perhaps even to storing, the data.

By the way, you're only looking for files whose paths contain no newlines. Those *are* permitted in file names. `edfig add` will happily add them.

### config_add

You seem to check the name against your subcommands, to make sure nobody accidentally uses the name `add` and ends up unable to access that config using `edfig add` (which has a different meaning). But you don't check for `-h` or `--help`, so `edfig add --help "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/some-util.conf"` works just fine. Which is a bit strange, since you *did* reserve `rm`, `edit`, `add`, `help` and `ls`, so it feels a bit inconsistent.

When validating the name, you're taking a length-1 substring, but checking it against the regex `^.*([!?.,])+.*$` which seems overcomplicated. It's a single character - the only way it's going to match that is if it also matches `[!?.,]`. Or if all of `$name` matches `^[!?.,]` for that matter.

Why are *those* characters in particular banned from the start of the name anyway? There doesn't seem to be an obvious reason to ban those but not also ban a bunch of others. And why only at the start - why is `edfig add .hello` worse than `edfig add h.ello`?

If given a relative path, you *save* the relative path. I could do something like `edfig add vim .vimrc` while standing in my home directory and it'll work fine, but then when I try to `edfig vim` it might fail, or even open *the wrong file*, depending on what directory I'm in. That's not ideal - you should probably store the full path.

You don't check whether the name is already in use. The program just adds another path at the end of the list, and then there are *two* paths under the same name, which seems to cause problems later on. I feel like utilities should make an effort to not corrupt their own configuration files - if the name is already in use you should either refuse to write another one, or replace the existing path for that name (though probably ask before replacing).

### config_edit

Don't assume people want their temporary files is `/tmp/` - you might not even be *able* to write to `/tmp`. `$TMPDIR` exists to let users control where their temporary files go, and `mktemp` already knows how to respect that , so use `mkdir --tmpdir config-XXX.tmp`.

Instead of `grep | wc -l`, you probably want `grep -c`. Also, you may want to quote that `grep` - it's *almost* certainly safe not to, but still.

### config_rm

Your approach here seems a bit overengineered. Couldn't the initial `awk` just grab every line *except* the one you want to remove? And then you could just write all those lines? Like, no tempfiles, just `awk -v "name=$name" '$1 != name' "$config_list" | sponge "$config_list"`?

Though, side note, if I add a file with a newline in its name, the part of the name that comes after the newline is just... left in the file. That doesn't seem ideal, especially since `edfig add` *does* allow me to add such files if I want to.

Why the `tee > /dev/null`s? If you only want to write to one location... you can just use redirection, right? So why `grep ... "$tempfile" | tee "$config_list" > /dev/null` instead of just `grep ... "$tempfile" > "$config_list"`?

Manually running the cleanup and then removing the exit trap seems unnecessary. You're about to exit either way. Just exit and let the trap handle the cleanup.

`grep -v "$line"` treats `$line` as a regex pattern - and it's taken from a file which can contain anything. It might end up matching things you don't want it to, causing too many config lines to be removed. Or if `$name` (and thus `$line`) begins with a `-`, `grep` could misinterpret it as a command line option of some kind. `grep -Fv -- "$line" "$tempfile"` avoids both those issues.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot recall the reason why did I put the name validation. Good advice, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> EDITOR="${EDITOR:-vi}"
> ```

Good!  Respect the user's choice of editor, and use the well-known environment variable to convey that.

---

> ```
> bold='\e[1m'
> red='\033[1;31m'
> green='\033[1;32m'
> reset='\033[0m'
> ```

Eww, please don't do that.  Even when output and error streams are connected to a terminal, not all terminals use the same escape sequences.  It's much better to use `tput` to generate control strings suitable for the actual terminal (or empty strings if not possible).  That leads to much nicer output (for example in the Emacs compilation buffer I'm using for testing).

---

> ```
> usage() {
>     short_usage
>     echo -e >&2
>     echo -e "${bold}Subcommands:${reset}" >&2
>     echo -e "  ${bold}add${reset}    Add new config file to list" >&2
>     ⋮
>     exit
> }
> ```

This is the kind of function you might want to take and adapt for other shell scripts, so it's best to avoid the Bash-specific `echo -e` there.  It's not clear why you're passing that option anyway, since you don't include any backslash-escapes to be expanded.

It may well be easier to `cat` from a here-document rather than have multiple commands to produce that output.

Personally, I would do the redirection to `&2` externally, to allow use of the same function for the error case (invalid arguments) and non-error case (help requested).  For the same reason, I would either `exit` from the caller or pass in the desired exit value, so that the error case can `exit 1` and the non-error case can `exit 0`.

```
usage() {
    short_usage
    cat <<END

${bold}Subcommands:${reset}
  ${bold}add${reset}    Add new config file to list
  ${bold}rm${reset}     Remove config file from list
  ${bold}edit${reset}   Edit an entry
  ${bold}ls${reset}     List all stored configs
  ${bold}help${reset}   Print this

${bold}Example:${reset}
  $CMD add vim \"\$HOME/.vimrc\"
  $CMD vim
  $CMD edit vim
  $CMD rm vim
  $CMD ls

$CMD is a command line tool to ease config files editing
END
}
```

```
case "${1:--}" in
    -)
        short_usage >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    help|-h|--help)
        usage
        exit 0
        ;;
esac
```

---

This check looks a bit odd, given that we're already within a `case` construct:

> ```
>     case "$name" in
>         add|edit|rm|ls|help)
>             msg_error "Reserved name. Please use another." 1
>             ;;
>         *)
>             if [[ "${name:0:1}" =~ ^.*([!?.,])+.*$ ]]; then
>                 msg_error "Cannot use ${bold}${name:0:1}${reset} as the begining of name." 1
>             fi
>             ;;
>     esac
> ```

It would be simpler to just check the invalid strings as another match:

```
    case "$name" in
        add|edit|rm|ls|help)
            msg_error "Reserved name. Please use another." 1
            ;;
        [!?.,]*)
            msg_error "Cannot use ${bold}${name:0:1}${reset} as the beginning of name." 1
            ;;
    esac
```

That also removes some more Bash-specific code, easing the way to making this a portable script.

We might want to perform some extra tests on the pathname: since we use newline as separator in our config file, the code will break if that's present in a filename.  And the current implementation will break if we use spaces (due to how we `cut` the contents), but that can be fixed.

---

Some of the error recovery looks surprising:

> ```
> cleanup() { rm -f "$tempfile"; }
> trap cleanup EXIT INT QUIT
> ```

It's good that we're using `trap`, and many shell programmers don't clean up robustly.  But it's strange to trap `INT` and `QUIT` with the same command as `EXIT`.  I think if we get one of those, we want to just take the default action, which is to exit (running the `EXIT` trap).  We don't want to just clean up and carry on!

Also, we have:

> ```
> cleanup &&
>     trap -- EXIT INT QUIT
>
> exit
> ```

This all seems unnecessary.  If we simply `exit`, then `cleanup` will be run, so there's no need to run it ourselves or to reset the trap.

---

Shellcheck suggests

```
note: Consider using grep -c instead of grep|wc -l. [SC2126]
```

---

It's usually an error to specify a specific directory for tempfiles like this:

```
tempfile=$(mktemp /tmp/config-XXX.tmp)
```

Just respect the user's `TMPDIR`.  In particular, specifying `/tmp` as we do can reduce security, since everyone can see what's in that directory, unlike the per-user directories created by `pam_tmpdir` on systems where that's used.

While considering security, it might be a good idea to set a more restrictive `umask` to keep the config files' contents private (which could be significant, e.g. if the file is a user's `.netrc`).

---

When we're storing filenames, we really should be converting them to absolute pathnames, since it's quite likely that we'll have changed working directory between the `add` and `edit` operations.

---

What's the point of `tee` here?

> ```
> grep -v "$line" "$tempfile" | tee "$config_list" > /dev/null ||
> ```

I don't see how that's different from simple

```
grep -v "$line" "$tempfile" >"$config_list" ||
```

We probably want to be using `grep -F`, to avoid treating any of the line as regexp metacharacters.

---

Having looked at this for a while, I don't think that storing our filename aliases in a file is really the right way to go.  If we use a directory instead, then each alias can be stored as a symbolic link, which solves many of the problems of the config file in one easy stroke.  For example, we can use normal filesystem operations to add or remove entries (without risk of breaking any others if the program crashes) and to test existence.

Comment: You know what, using symlinks is actually a good idea! Might try it some other time